# hosting a wordpress site from dev to production

Tags: wordpress, server, migration, hosting

I have a WordPress site hosted in my server with www.domain.com and I'm building another version of the website in a subdomain www.subdomain.domain.com/wordpress/, I want to replace the first version by the second, I font know how to do that and replace the databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

I think the easiest is this:

Install the plugin [Duplicator](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) on your new site (in dev environment) and create a back-up (with duplicator).

Prepare the new location:

- back-up and remove any excisting site content.
- back-up(if needed) and completely empty the new database (or create a new DB).

Upload the duplicator backup files (there are 2 files: .zip & .php) to the new location.

Go to: example.com/installer.php.

You will then see a duplicator back-up/migration install screen, follow the steps.
Because you're changing the domain, you'll have to update the database with the new domain, duplicator can do this for you. Carefully follow each step and read everything.

Google it, if you're not sure about something, duplicator is widely used.

I found a step by step post [here](https://www.wpkube.com/move-backup-website-wordpress-duplicator-plugin/), but it's from 2015 and may be a bit outdated.

Regards, Bjorn